# Ho to apply DAO to XPages

Tags: java, xpages, dao

I would like to apply MVC principles to my XPages application. To understand the Data Access Object pattern I looked at the following tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/data_access_object_pattern.htm

However I have some difficulties trying to make the translation to an XPages application. Where should I place the dialog with reading/writing data from an NSF? how abstract should I make it?

Is there a base example available where 1 type of object/document is used that I can take a look at?

Comment: Hi Malin - I don't know if it helps, but I use a cut down form of this MVC http://www.pipalia.co.uk/notes-development/rethinking-xpages-part-one/

Comment: Thank you! I also noticed a sample application. I have some study to do :-)

Comment: It took me a while to become comfortable with the concept but now it is fine. That said I combine the CRUD and the DAO. I understand why they would be separate but it seemed to overcomplicate things for my applications.